# Pandas in df column extract string after colon if colon exits; if not, keep text

Tags: python, pandas

Looked for awhile on here, but couldn't find the answer.

```
df['Products'] = ['CC: buns', 'people', 'CC: help me']
```

Trying to get only text after colon or keep text if no colon is in the string.

Tried a lot of things, but this was my final attempt.

```
x['Product'] = x['Product'].apply(lambda i: i.extract(r'(?i):(.+)') if ':' in i else i)
```

I get this error:

Might take two steps, I assume.

I tried this:

```
x['Product'] = x['Product'].str.extract(r'(?i):(.+)')
```

Got me everything after the colon and a bunch of NaN, so my regex is working. I am assuming my lambda sucks.

Comment: what's the error/

Answer (score 5):

Use `str.split` and get last item

```
df['Products'] =  df['Products'].str.split(': ').str[-1]

Out[9]:
    Products
0       buns
1     people
2    help me
```

Comment: easiest way for sure..even handles no colon

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried this, since I used a similar line of code for another column. Must have made a small error I didn't notice late last night. Voted it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df['Products'] = df.Products.apply(lambda x: x.split(': ')[-1] if ':' in x else x)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Products
0     buns
1   people
2  help me
```